# Codeigniter - Database select

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Hi,

I need a help related to Codeigniter very badly.

I have some problems with a database query, i'am new to Codeigniter.

I have 3 tables:

```
1) film(film_id, filmname) PK (film_id)
2) category(category_id, categoryname) PK (category_id)
3) film_category(contains both primary keys (film_id) and (category_id))
```

The problem is that I want to `select all filmname from film tables where category_id = 3`.

How to do this with active record class?

Please make a suggestion.

I'am new to Codeigniter and I love it.

Thank you in advance from your friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```
$this->db->select('f.filmname');
$this->db->join('film_category fc', 'fc.film_id = f.film_id');
$this->db->where('fc.category_id', 3);
$query = $this->db->get('film f');
```

I find the ActiveRecord one of the most useful and elegant parts of CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

### select data from the database in descending order

`$this->db->order_by("id","desc");
 $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
 return $query->result();`

Comment: retrieve table data in descending order based on table id

Comment: could you please add some details on your answer ?